# webpy with nginx + mod_wsgi template file cannot be found

Tags: python, nginx, mod-wsgi, web.py

I am using webpy with nginx + mod_wsgi.
To import modules(controllers etc.), I wrote

```
curdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(curdir)
```

in app.py, and corresponding nginx configuration is

```
wsgi_pass /path/to/app.py
```

As usual, I put all templates in a folder named templates, and in webpy

```
render = weg.template.render('templates')
```

This method results in path problem, template files can not be found.
How can I do configuration correctly? Thanks a lot.

**Update**: problem solved with appending

```
os.chdir(curdir)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relying on the current working directory being a specific location is bad practice. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory

You should instead use absolute paths instead of relative paths.

You can construct absolute paths relative to 'curdir' rather than actually changing location to that directory.